# How to record data under HDF5 file correctly

Tags: python, audio, hdf5, feature-extraction, h5py

I am getting `Type Error: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent`.
Here is my python code;
dtype for `mel_train, mfcc_train, and y_train` are all `float32`.
Array shapes are: `mfcc_train: (6398,)` ; `mel_train: (6398,)` and `y_train: (6398, 16)`.

```
with h5py.File(train_file,'w') as f:
    f['mfcc_train'] = mfcc_train
    f['mel_train'] = mel_train
    f['y_train'] = y_train
```

Comment: Object dtype aka `dtype('O')` usually refers to arrays of arrays. Could also be arrays of other object types. Please provide `.dtype` and `.shape` for each of the arrays. Also, please clean-up formatting to mark all code and clarify what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for your response.mfcc_train , mel_train and y_train have the float32 type and they are extracted from different *.wav files.                                                        Here is my python code:

Comment: Thank you for your response.mfcc_train , mel_train and y_train have the float32 type and they are extracted from different *.wav files. These three variables have respectively the following shape: mfcc_train is (6398,)  ; mel_train is (6398,) and y_train is (6398, 16).    Here is my python code:

Comment: with h5py.File(train_file,'w') as f:
    f['mel_train'] = mel_train
    f['mfcc_train'] = mfcc_train
    f['y_train'] = y_train

Comment: mel_train = []
mel_valid = []
mel_test = []
mfcc_train = []
mfcc_valid = []
mfcc_test = []

for i in range(train_csv.shape[0]):
    sr, audio = wavfile.read(train_csv.iloc[i,0])
    audio = pad_input(audio)
    mel = normalise_feature(extract_mel(audio))
    mfcc = normalise_feature(extract_mfcc(audio))
    mel_train.append(mel.T)
    mfcc_train.append(mfcc.T)
mel_train = np.asarray(mel_train)
mfcc_train = np.asarray(mfcc_train)
y = train_csv.iloc[:,1].to_list()
y_train = change.str2bin(y)
train_file = os.path.join(feature_dir,'mel_mfcc_train.h5')

Comment: Please add the code in comments to your post and format as code. (I started editing, but don't know where the code in the last comment goes -- I think _**before**_ the call to create the HDF5 file?) Also, when do you get the Object dtype error? When you create the file, or when you try to read the data from the file? _Something_ in your code is creating an object that is not a standard numpy ndarray -- not clear what yet. Need more info to diagnose.

Comment: Please, see the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import h5py
import pickle
from utils import change_label, make_dir
# open training, validation, and testing sets from csv files
train_csv = pd.read_csv("training.csv",index_col=0)
valid_csv = pd.read_csv("validation.csv",index_col=0)
test_csv = pd.read_csv("testing.csv",index_col=0)
feature_dir = 'features' # directory to store the extracted features
make_dir(feature_dir) # create directory if it does not exist
mel_train = []
mel_valid = []
mel_test = []
mfcc_train = []
mfcc_valid = []
mfcc_test = []
change = change_label() # to encode string label (class name) 
into binary matrix or vice versa
for i in range(train_csv.shape[0]):
   sr, audio = wavfile.read(train_csv.iloc[i,0])
   audio = pad_input(audio)
   mel = normalise_feature(extract_mel(audio))
   mfcc = normalise_feature(extract_mfcc(audio))
   mel_train.append(mel.T)
   mfcc_train.append(mfcc.T)
mel_train = np.asarray(mel_train)
print(mel_train.shape)
mfcc_train = np.asarray(mfcc_train)
print(mfcc_train.shape)
y = train_csv.iloc[:,1].to_list()
y_train = change.str2bin(y)
print(y_train.shape)
train_file = os.path.join(feature_dir,'mel_mfcc_train.h5')
print ("Storing extracted features and associated label 
 from training set     into a file: "+train_file)
with h5py.File(train_file,'w') as f:
    f['mel_train'] = mel_train
    f['mfcc_train'] = mfcc_train
    f['y_train'] = y_train`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I ***think*** I know what's going on (educated guess). You extract the audio data to arrays `mel` and `mfcc`, then add to lists `mel_train` and `mfcc_train` (looping over 6398 audio files). After you exit the loop, you convert the lists to arrays. If every `mel` and `mfcc` array has the same shape (say `(m,n)`) the new arrays would be shape `(6398,m,n)`, where 6398 is `len(mel_train)`. However, I suspect each `mel` and `mfcc` array has a different shape. As a result, when you convert the list of differently shaped arrays to a single array, you will get an array shape of `(6398,)` with `dtype=object` (where the objects are `float32` arrays).

To demonstrate the difference, I created an 2 nearly identical examples:

1. Creates 5 arrays of ***identical*** 2d shape `(10,2)`, adds to a list, then converts the list to an array. Note how the final array is shape `(5,10,2)` and dtype is `float64`. You can create a HDF5 dataset directly from this array.
2. Creates 5 arrays of ***variable*** 2d shape, adds to a list, then converts the list to an array. Note how the final array is shape `(5,)` and dtype is `object`. You ***cannot*** create a HDF5 dataset directly from this array. This is why you get `TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent`.

Note: I added `dtype=object` to the `np.asarray()` function for the second method to avoid the `VisibleDeprecationWarning`.

Example 2 shows 2 methods to load data. It continues from Example 1 and loads data into the same HDF5 file. After you run them, you can compare dataset `mel_train1`, group `mel_train2` and dataset `mel_train3`. Each has a "Note" attribute to describe the data.

**Code below:**

**Example 1 - constant shape arrays:**

```
train_file = 'mel_mfcc_train.h5'

## Example 1 - Create arrays of constant shape 
a0, a1, n = 10, 2, 5
mel_train = [] 

for i in range(n):         
    arr = np.random.random(a0*a1).reshape(a0,a1)
    mel_train.append(arr) 

print('\nFor mel_train arrays of constant size:')
print(f'Size of mel_train list: {len(mel_train)}')
mel_train = np.asarray(mel_train) 
print(f'For mel_train array: Dtype: {mel_train.dtype}; Shape: {mel_train.shape}')

with h5py.File(train_file,'w') as f: 
    f['mel_train1'] = mel_train
    f['mel_train1'].attrs['Note'] = f'{n} Constant shaped arrays: {a0} x {a1}'
```

**Example 2 - variable shape arrays:**

```
## Example 2 - Create arrays of random shape 
mel_train = [] 

for i in range(n): 
    a0 = np.random.randint(6,10) # set a0 dimension to random length
    ##a1 = np.random.randint(3,6)        
    arr = np.random.random(a0*a1).reshape(a0,a1)
    mel_train.append(arr) 

print('\nFor mel_train arrays of random size:')
print(f'Size of mel_train list: {len(mel_train)}')
# mel_train = np.asarray(mel_train) 
mel_train = np.asarray(mel_train,dtype=object) 
print(f'For mel_train array: Dtype: {mel_train.dtype}; Shape: {mel_train.shape}')  
for i, arr in enumerate(mel_train):
    print(f'\tFor a0= {i}; shape: {arr.shape}')
```

**Loading Example 2 data as-is will throw an exception**

```
# Creating a dataset with arrays of different sizes will throw
# an exception (exception trapped and printed in code below)   
try: 
    with h5py.File(train_file,'a') as f: 
        f['mel_train2'] = mel_train 
except Exception as e:
    print(f'\nh5py Exception: {e}\n')
```

**Recommended method to load Example 2 data**

```
## Example 2A
# To avoid exception, write each object/array to seperate datasets in 1 group    
with h5py.File(train_file,'a') as f: 
    grp = f.create_group('mel_train2')
    f['mel_train2'].attrs['Note'] = f'1 group and {n} datasets for variable shaped arrays'
    for i, arr in enumerate(mel_train):
        f[f'mel_train2/dataset_{i:04}'] = arr
```

**Alternate method to load Example 2 data (not recommended)**

```
## Example 2B - for completeness; NOT recommended
# Alternately, size dataset to hold largest array.
# dataset will have zeros where smaller arrays are loaded

ds_dtype = mel_train[0].dtype
ds_a0 = mel_train.shape[0]
ds_a1, ds_a2 = 0, 0
for arr in mel_train:
    ds_a1 = max(ds_a1, arr.shape[0])
    ds_a2 = max(ds_a2, arr.shape[1])
    
with h5py.File(train_file,'a') as f: 
    ds2 = f.create_dataset('mel_train2',dtype=ds_dtype,shape=(ds_a0,ds_a1,ds_a2))
    for i, arr in enumerate(mel_train):
        j,k = arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]
        ds2[i,0:j,0:k] = arr
```

**Typical output from running code above:**

```
For mel_train arrays of constant size:
Size of mel_train list: 5
For mel_train array: Dtype: float64; Shape: (5, 10, 2)

For mel_train arrays of random size:
Size of mel_train list: 5
For mel_train array: Dtype: object; Shape: (5,)
    For a0= 0; shape: (6, 2)
    For a0= 1; shape: (7, 2)
    For a0= 2; shape: (8, 2)
    For a0= 3; shape: (6, 2)
    For a0= 4; shape: (9, 2)

h5py Exception: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear for your continuous assistance.I have tried the first suggestion and It has worked for me. Here is the completed python code for training:

Comment: I wrote my previous comment under the wrong "answer". I am reposting here for clarity. Glad this answer solved your problem. It took awhile to diagnose and replicate the Object dtype error message. If this solved your problem, please mark this answer as Accepted. BTW, although I showed how to load arrays of different shapes into 1 dataset, I don't recommend doing that. Reading each array correctly will be tricky. It would be much better to load each array into a separate dataset. When I get time, I will modify the answer to show that method.